# Are there race conditions in this producer-consumer implementation?

Tags: c, multithreading, producer-consumer

In section 3.4.1 of Operating System Concepts (Silberschatz, 9th edition), the authors present the producer-consumer problem and give the following implementation that uses a circular buffer (page 125, 126).

```
//Shared variables

#define BUFFER SIZE 10
struct Item;
Item buffer[BUFFER SIZE];
int in = 0, out = 0;

//buffer is empty when  in == out
//buffer is full when   (in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE == out

//Producer
while (true)
{
    Item next_produced = /*produce item here*/;

    while (((in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE) == out) ; //do nothing

    buffer[in] = next_produced;
    in = (in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE;
}

//Consumer
while (true)
{   
    while (in == out) ;  //do nothing

    Item next_consumed = buffer[out];
    out = (out + 1) % BUFFER SIZE;

    //consume the item in next_consumed here
}
```

The book says:

> One issue this illustration does not address concerns the situation in
>   which both the producer process and the consumer process attempt to
>   access the shared buffer concurrently.

I do not see a situation where the producer and consumer would access the **same** buffer element simultaneously.

My question is: if the producer and consumer ran in two threads, are there race conditions or other synchronization problems in this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of possibilities

1. The most obvious: if there are 2 producer producing data.  Assuming there is only 1 free space in the buffer, both producer thread can get pass the `while (in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE) == out` and try to put to the buffer.  This can lead to corrupted buffer or missing data
2. Even there is only 1 consumer and 1 producer, there are still some less obvious problem.  For example, compiler may rearrange the lines

   ```
   buffer[in] = next_produced;
   in = (in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE;
   ```

   to make the update of `in` happen earlier than update of `buffer`, which cause the consumer accessing uninitialized data.

Comment: Please elaborate #2 `compiler may rearrange the lines`. Simply swapping the lines would obviously produce different behavior, so I guess you rather meant something along the line of "the compiler may rearrange it as `{ int temp = in; in = (in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE; buffer[temp] = next_produced; }`". However, such rewrite would have different UB if `in` were an out-of-bounds index (which could result e.g. in an exception being thrown). In the original code the `in` at the point of UB would be invalid, in the rewrite it would be valid. Is such a rewrite really allowed by the C standard?

Comment: Quite a lot of languages allow compiler to re-order instructions for the sake of optimization.  Just Google for "c++ compiler reorder instruction optimization" will give you quite some information.

Comment: @dxiv In addition, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model

Comment: Adrian, I do not think such rearragment can happen. Compiler is only allowed rearrangments which will not change the behaviour in a single-threaded system. If you swap two lines, you will end up with different behavior on single-threaded system.

Comment: I am not a _language_ _lawyer_ so I asked this as a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823457/c-observable-behavior-in-the-context-of-ub-undefined-behavior).

Comment: @AdrianShum Thanks for the answer. If we assume that the code executes exactly in the order it appears, is this a correct solution to the single producer single consumer case? I was more interested in the theoretical correctness of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that a write to `buffer[x]` would be seen before a modification of `in` or `out`

So assuming only one reader and one writer, then the in, out variables are each modified in a single thread.

```
buffer[in] = next_produced;
in = (in + 1) % BUFFER SIZE;
```

Could be seen mis-ordered in the reader, causing the reader to see in moved, but the old value of buffer[in]

```
Item next_consumed = buffer[out];
out = (out + 1) % BUFFER SIZE;
```

Could be misordered by the compiler, or the processor, allowing the producer to write into the full queue overwriting the value of `buffer[out]` before the `next_consumed` has read the value.