# C "observable behavior" in the context of UB "undefined behavior"

Tags: c, language-lawyer

(Question was originally prompted by comments under this answer to [Are there race conditions in this producer-consumer implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34805749/5538420) but is being asked here strictly from the C language perspective, without any concurrency or multi-threading involved.)

Consider this minimal code:

```
#define BUFSIZ 10
char buf[BUFSIZ];

void f(int *pn)
{
    buf[*pn]++;
    *pn = (*pn + 1) % BUFSIZ;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    f(&n);
    return n; 
}
```

Question: would the C *"as-if"* rules allow the compiler to rewrite the code as follows?

```
void f(int *pn)
{
    int n = *pn;
    *pn = (*pn + 1) % BUFSIZ;
    buf[n]++;
}
```

On one hand, the above would not change the observable behavior of the program as written.

On the other hand, `f` could get called with an invalid index, possibly from another translation unit:

```
int g()
{
    int n = -1001;
    f(&n);
}
```

In this latter case, both variants of the code would invoke UB when accessing the out-of-bounds array element. However, the original code would leave `*pn` at the value being passed into `f` (= -1001) while the rewritten code would step into UB-land only after modifying `*pn` (to `0`).

Would such a difference count as "observable" or, back to the actual question, is there anything in the C standard that would specifically allow or preclude this type of code rewrite/optimization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If any part of your program has undefined behaviour, then the behaviour of the entire program is undefined. In other words, the behaviour of the program is undefined even "before" any construct whose behaviour is undefined. (This is necessary to allow the compiler to perform certain optimizations which depend on behaviour being defined.)
2. Given that neither variable is declared as volatile, I believe it is possible that the order of memory updates would be reordered as indicated, since observable behaviour is only guaranteed to be according to the execution model in the absence of undefined behaviour.
3. "Observable behaviour" (in Standard C) is defined in §5.1.2.3 as:

   > - Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
   > - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
   > - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to
   >     a program waiting for input.

   This list does not include any potential response to undefined behaviour (such as a trap or signal), even though in vernacular terms a segfault is normally observable. The particular example in the question does not involve any of these three points. (The UB could prevent the program from successfully terminating, which basically voids the second point in observable behaviour.) So in the particular case of the code in the question, reordering would not alter any observable behaviour and could clearly be performed.
4. My statement that the implementation's response to undefined behaviour is not limited to execution strictly following the component which engenders undefined behaviour created a lot more controversy in the comments thread than I expected, since it is a fairly well-known feature of modern C. It may be worth reviewing John Regehr's useful [essay](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) on [undefined](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/226) [behaviour](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232), from which I quote: (in the third part)

   > More specifically, when a program dies due to performing an illegal operation such as dividing by zero or dereferencing a null pointer, is this considered to be side effecting? The answer is definitely “no.” … Since crash-inducing operations are not side effecting, the compiler can reorder them with respect to other operations,

   As a possibly more interesting example (taken from the comments thread), if a program produces several lines of output, and then deliberately executes an explicit divide-by-zero, one might expect that compiling and running the program would produce the output before responding in whatever undefined way it responds to the divide-by-zero. However, a compiler which detected the divide-by-zero and could prove that the control flow of the program guaranteed its execution would be perfectly entitled to produce an error message *at translation time* and refuse to produce an executable image.

   Alternatively, if it could not prove that control flow reached the divide-by-zero, it would be entitled to assume that the divide-by-zero could not happen, and therefore remove all code unequivocally leading up to the divide-by-zero (including the calls to the output function) as dead code.

   Both of the above fit into the list of example responses to undefined behaviour in §3.4.3: "from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, … to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)."

Comment: This is simply not true. Undefined behavior can be caused by input. I can obtain a partial output from a program, and then pass that output into a part of the universe which is causally disconnected. After that, I can give the program an input that causes UB.  The valid output that had been obtained cannot be revoked (it is physically impossible to do so; we have communicated it to a causally disconnected region of space-time).

Comment: That is to say, even if the UB causes some catastrophic event, like a supernova explosion, the previous result is impervious to destruction.

Comment: @kaz: I believe that time travel is impossible, whether or not the C standard allows it. Nonetheless, the standard frees the implementation from all responsibility for the execution of a program whose behaviour is undefined. That freedom extends to obeying the physical laws of the universe, of course, and I think it is highly likely that UB caused by input would not retroactively affect program execution, but that's not required by the standard, even if it is required by common sense...

Comment: Anyway, the example in the OP did not involve input. And even if it did, the compiler is entitled to compile `f` without worrying about UB, which means that it is perfectly acceptable to perform a reordering optimization which also reorders UB but does not affect observable behaviour in the absence of UB.

Comment: So you mean if I download a file from an some Apache server today, and tomorrow that server crashes, my file (whose SHA256 verifies okay and everything) can vaporize, even though I've disconnected from the server  and unplugged the network cable? Sorry, what you're saying doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @kaz: I'm not saying that. I'm only saying that it is not the C standard which guarantees the non-vaporization of your file.

Comment: `If any part of your program has undefined behaviour, then the behaviour of the entire program is undefined, starting at the beginning.` Thanks for the insight, but would you have an authoritative reference for an unambiguous statement to that effect?

Comment: @kaz: To be a bit more down-to-earth: the C standard gives the implementation license to do anything *that it is capable of doing* in the face of undefined behaviour. There are obviously other constraints.

Comment: You're just making this up. Where is it documented that undefined behavior reaches back in time and erases correct computation?

Comment: Isn't the time-causation-teleportation-perl6 stuff just tangential? if a C compiler is allowed to re-order the instructions (equivalent to the proposed code) there is no reason to 'go back in time' based on the input - http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3978

Comment: @dxiv: Basically, the standard requires a conforming implementation to execute a conforming program according to the requirements. What an implementation does with a non-conforming program is unspecified. If an implementation can *prove* that a program will eventually execute a construct with undefined behaviour, it can, for example, not execute the program, which is certainly before the execution of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kaz: You're wilfully misinterpreting license as obligation. Nowhere did I say that UB "reaches back in time and erases correct computation". My claim is that the implementation is permitted to fail to perform a correct computation because of something which will happen in the future. In particular, it can reorder A and B on the assumption that B will not break the rules, even if that means that if B *does* break the rules, A won't happen. (Your local laws do not prohibit you from time travelling. That is hardly an assumption that it would be possible.)

Comment: @rici I would still appreciate an authoritative reference, this is why I tagged the question as `language-lawyer`. I can see your point, though not sure I agree, or the standard agrees with it. If I write a C program that printf's "unplug this computer *now*" in a 1,000,000 loop then does an explicit divide-by-zero, my expectation would be to see some printf's prior to the UB.

Comment: Yes you did; you said that as soon as UB happens at any time, the whole program is undefined *even "before" any construct whose behavior is undefined*. Exact quote!

Comment: @kaz: Yes, that's what I said. I said that it is undefined, meaning that whatever happens is no longer regulated by the C standard.

Comment: Fact is, C has abstract semantics, which produces certain externally visible effects, like the contents of files written using I/O streams. If some result having gone into a file is observed, then even if subsequent UB destroys the file, the observation in fact took place and attests to the fact that things were well-defined up to that point.

Comment: "No longer regulated" means "from now on, going forward".

Comment: @dxiv: That would certainly be the expectation of many people. But if during the *compilation*, the compiler issued an error message telling you that the program would necessarily divide-by-zero, and then failed to produce a object file, would you consider that a bug or a feature? The C standard doesn't require a compiler to do that, obviously, but I believe it *permits* it. It would also permit the compiler to issue a warning, or require agreement from you by way of a command-line option in order to produce the object file it knows will blow up.

Comment: @dxiv: The clear unambiguous statement in the C++ standard -- "if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this International
Standard places no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to operations preceding the first undefined operation)" -- does not appear in the C standard. Nonetheless, I believe that both standards work from the same basic principle, so it is deducible. Also see John Regehr's useful essay on UB (http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232), which speaks to the precise case in the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, and the extended answer. Both C++ and (especially) C sound rather evasive on the matter, which I guess it's part of their don't-over-specify philosophy.